# Stray characters in char array

Tags: c, malloc

I am having a problem with this code, this code is a encryption for a rail cipher and if you enter in an input "testing" you should get an output "tietnsg" which i do get.

However if i change the input to "testingj" i  get an output of "tietnjsgp?²!Ç‰" i can see from my debugging the "?²!Ç‰" appears to be tagged on during the last fill in the `toCipher` function
does anyone know how to fix it other than the way that i did it?

```
/*
    CIS Computer Secutrity Program 1
    10-10-14
*/
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <malloc.h>

char *toCipher(char **arr,int x,int y);
char *Encrypt(char *pT, int size);
char **create(int x,int y);
void FreeArr(char **array, int y);
void print(char *word,int strl);

int main(){
    char pt[]= "testingj";
    char *word = Encrypt(pt,3);
    print(word, sizeof(pt));
    free(word);

}

/*
Take in a pointer to a word, and the lenght of the string
Post print each char in the array, (used beacuase i had some issues with the memory, i keep getting extra adresses
*/
void print(char *word,int strl){
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<strl-1;i++){
        printf("this is correct %c",word[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

/*
Pre, take in the pointer to the plain text word to be encrypted as well as the depth of the Encryption desired
Post: Construct the array, insert values into the 2d array, convert the 2d array to a 1d array and return the 1d array
*/

char *Encrypt(char *word,int y){
    int x = strlen(word);
    int counter=0;
    int ycomp=0;
    int rate=1;

    char **rail = create(x,y);

        while(counter<x){   
            if(ycomp==y-1){
                rate=-1;
            }
            if(ycomp==0){
                rate=1;         
            }
            rail[counter][ycomp]=word[counter]; 
            ycomp=ycomp+rate;
            counter++;
        }//end of rail construction

    char *DrWord = toCipher(rail,x,y);  

    FreeArr(rail,y);    
    return(DrWord);
}


/*
Create a dynamic 2d array of chars for the rail cypher to use
Take in the dimensions
return the pointer of the rails initial address, after it created the space for the rail
*/


char *toCipher(char **arr,int x,int y){
    int xI =0;
    int yI=0;
    int counter =0;
    char *word = (char*)malloc(x);
    int i;


    for(yI=0;yI<y;yI++){    
        for(xI=0;xI<x;xI++){
            if(arr[xI][yI]!= 0){                    
                word[counter]=arr[xI][yI];
                counter++;
            }
        }

    }
        printf("this is the problem %s\n",word);
        return(word);
}




char **create(int x, int y){
    char **rail;            
    int i,j;

    rail = malloc(sizeof(char**)*x);

    for(i=0;i<x;i++){
        rail[i]= (char*)malloc(y * sizeof(char*));
    }

    for(i=0;i<y;i++){
        for(j=0;j<x;j++){
            rail[j][i]= 0;
        }
    }

    return(rail);
}


/*
Pre, take in a malloc'd array, with the height of the array 
free the malloc calls one by one, and finally free the initial adress
*/
void FreeArr(char **array, int y){
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<y;i++){
        free(array[i]);
    }
    free(array);
}
```

Comment: Although most probably not the cause of your issue, this `char ** rail; rail = malloc(sizeof(char**)*x);` is shall at least be `... rail = malloc(sizeof(char*)*x);`. Or even better: `... rail = malloc(x * sizeof *rail);`

Comment: I believe `char *word = (char*)malloc(x);` in `toCipher` should be `char *word = malloc(sizeof(word) * x)`, but I may be wrong.

Comment: By any means allocate N times what the target **is pointing to**, so it would be `char * word = malloc(x * sizeof *word);` @Namfuak

Comment: @alk I knew I was missing something.

Comment: with this "char *word = malloc(x*sizeof(word));"  i keep getting a tagged memory block .MSC tagged onto the end of my array

Comment: Try debugging your code by tracing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `toCipher`, the `word` is printed without nul-termination.  Either:

```
char *word = (char*)malloc(x+1); // allocate an extra char for nul.
word[x] = 0; // add the nul at the end.
```

or:

```
printf("this is the problem %.*s\n",x,word); // limit characters printed to x.
```

Comment: my solution was to initialize the characters in word to null, but this would have worked as well, chars terminate at the null character, or where you tell it to stop

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to initialize word to 0, the tagged memory if you watch it in debug mode was not being replaced, therefore was tagged along in the newly constructed string